# WebSocket instantiation and onerror callback - is it always called?

Tags: websocket

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#creating_a_websocket_object), creating a `WebSocket` object automatically tries to open the connection. If there is an error, the `error` event is fired, causing the `onerror` callback to be called.

What bugs me is that I first have to create the object and therefore to (try to) open the connection, and only then I can set my own `onerror` callback. How can I ensure that a connection error really does trigger the callback? Or in other words, what if the error manages to take place before the callback is set? Or is it somehow guaranteed that this does not happen?

Comment: Your code is interpreted before executed, if you create the WebSocket object and assign "instantly" a `onerror` event handler it gets fired 100%